# I want to use getters and setters for a game table

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

Hi Im trying to set up a person class for each player on a leaderboard, since i dont know how long the leader board is im going to try and loop the amount of people by the count of the rows in the leaderboard. Then im trying to "get" the points for each row and compare each one again the previous to assert the higher number is one the top, ive never used getters and setters before and cant seem to figure out how to do this, any help??

Here is the code for the information i want for each person, I need to find the player_picks, position and player_points . I then need to compare the count of each player_picks total with each player as i go down the leaderboard. If the pick_total is is equal i then need to compare their points total.Ive been trying this for a few weeks but someone suggested it would be easier making a player class and then using get and setters to assign attributes to each of them. SO i could then compare player1 with player 2, player 2 and player 3 etc. Whats making mit difficult is that i dont know the size of the list each time so its confusing me.

Below is the code im using which gives me the attributes im look to "set" but i dont know how to set up a "people" in a person class as the amount of people required each time with be changing (using int size) as a different amount of people join each game.

Im new to this so if im not explaining this well let me know.

```
public void test_player_leaderboard_entry() {
    int size = playerRows.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //Position
        String position_first_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-position-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Points
        String points_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-points-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Username
        String username_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-player-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Row Number
        Integer row = i + 1;
        Integer total_of_won_and_looking_good = 0;
        //PICKS
        for (int pick_number = 1; pick_number < 5; pick_number++) {
            String pick_status = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/section[2]/section/div/ol/a[" + row + "]/li/div[3]/div[" + pick_number + "]/div")).getAttribute("data-qa-pick-state");
            //System.out.println(pick_status);
            if (Integer.parseInt(pick_status) == 2 || Integer.parseInt(pick_status) == 1) {
                total_of_won_and_looking_good = total_of_won_and_looking_good + 1;

            }
            //System.out.println(total_of_won_and_looking_good);
        }

        //System.out.println("On row number " + row + " we find " + username_player + " in position " + position_first_player + " with " + total_of_won_and_looking_good + " correct picks and " + points_player + " points!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean, you are scraping a leaderboard from a webpage and would like to sort the entries in descending order? Forget the programming terminology; I would recommend explaining what you want to accomplish in plain-english so that a programmer could then look at your requirements and then attempt to explain to you what your approach should be.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not attempting to set up a person class for each player on a leaderboard, you are attempting to design a Person class and instantiate a Person object for each person row on the leaderboard. I would heavily suggest reading the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) and learning more about classes and objects.

Within your loop you will want to create a new Person object, scrape the necessary value, call the appropriate setter with the value and add that player object to a collection. e.g.

```
Person p = new Person() //create new Person object
int points = Integer.parseInt(Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-points-value='" + i + "']")).getText());
p.setPoints(points); //call setter for points field
personList.add(p); //add person to list
```

An example of a simple person class could look like the following. Note that implementing the Comparable interface allows for Person objects to be sorted when stored in a List or array as seen below.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> { 

    private int score;

    public Person() { }

    public void setScore(int score) { this.score = score; }

    public int getScore() { return this.score; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        Person p2 = new Person();
        p1.setScore(80);
        p2.setScore(90);
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(p1);
        people.add(p2);
        System.out.println("Before sorting: " + people.toString());
        Collections.sort(people);
        System.out.println("After sorting: " + people.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        if (p.getScore() > this.score)
            return 1;
        if (p.getScore() < this.score)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person -> score: %d", this.score);
    }
}
```